# Output student number that exists only on primary key but doesn't exist on foreign key

Tags: sql

I have two tables

`Student` table

- student number  primary key

`Grade` table

- student number  foreign key

I want to display only students that exist in the `student` table but don't exist in the `grade` table

Comment: so whats your problem is ?

Comment: This is a direct translation to SQL: `select * from students as s where not exists (select * fron grade as g where g.student_id = s.student_id)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way you can select all students that are not found (by their id) in the grade table.

```
SELECT * 
FROM student 
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT student_id FROM grade)
```

Comment: Because this is a forieng key and student_id is not likely to allowed to be null this will probably work.  However when using NOT IN or IN in this pattern you need to make sure the list obtained in your inner query cannot have a NULL value or you will not get the results that you desire.  NOT IN (SELECT student_id FROM grade WHERE student_id IS NOT NULL) would be more for certain

Answer (score 0):

Just to round out the answers I usually prefer using joins for things like this a simple left join and testing for null value will do the trick.

```
SELECT s.*
FROM
    student s
    LEFT JOIN grade g
WHERE
    g.student_Id IS NULL
```